# Iterate javascript objects

Tags: javascript, json

Good Day!

How do I get values on my json via dot(.) syntax??

here is my json data:

```
[
{"productName":"31","description":"this is a red item","quantity":"","price":"15"},
{"productName":"35","description":"this color is blue","quantity":"","price":"600"}]
```

I tried using

```
var temp = $.cookie('Table_Rows'); <-- which contains the json data above;

for (var key in temp ) {
if (temp.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
  var obj = temp[key];
  for (var prop in obj) {
     if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        console.log(prop + " = " + obj[prop]);
     }
   }
  }
}
```

then I got this log on my console:

```
0 = [
0 = {
0 = "
0 = p
0 = r
0 = o
0 = d
0 = u
0 = c
0 = t
0 = N
0 = a
and so on..
```

Can you please help me comeup with a correct method please..
I want to access it like `temp.productName`. I know that this must be an easy fix, but its really confusing me right now. Thank you and have a nice day!

Comment: You need to parse it first.  `var data = JSON.parse(temp);`.

Comment: Yep. What you get from the cookie is not JSON until you parse it ;)

Comment: @Bommox: Actually, it *is* JSON.  Once you parse it, it becomes an object.  JSON is a string format.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the help! totally saves me! thats what Im missing all this time! dat JSON.parse() thing..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array contains *product* items which you can access using a simple array index accessor.

**But first, parse your cookie string object to JSON:**

```
var jsonArray = JSON.parse(temp);
```

**And then you should came up with:**

```
var jsonArray = [{
    productName: "31",
    description: "this is a red item",
    quantity: "",
    price: "15"
}, {
    productName: "35",
    description: "this color is blue",
    quantity: "",
    price: "600"
}];
```

**Which you can iterate like this:**

```
for (obj in jsonArray) {
    console.log(jsonArray[obj].productName);
}
```

**And get the following output:**

```
31
35
```

See my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ynevet/T3Yr5/) example for full code version.

Comment: thank you @Yair Nevet for your answer! it worked perfectly! By the way in first its not working, then  I realized I need to parse my data first! saves my day!

Comment: @melvnberd Yes, I know, see my update. Happy to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to turn the JSON you get from the cookie value into a JavaScript object using JSON.parse

Then you can access the productName using an array method that is available in ES5

```
temp.forEach(function(item){ console.log(item.productName) });
```